# Flyout,Menu Flyout ,Combo Box occupy full screen in windows phone 8.1

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing an app in which combo box flyouts and menu flyouts are used ,But when I am using it , it occupy full screen in windows phone 8.1 ,Is this a default behavior or it can be controlled?

```
                <Button.Flyout>
                    <Flyout Opened="Flyout_Opened">
                        <Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="FlyoutPresenter">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#004469"></Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Foreground="White" Text="Create Text" FontSize="25" Margin="0,0,0,10"  />
                            <TextBox x:Name="setText" Width="300" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                            <Button x:Name="addText" Background="#c0c0c0" Foreground="#004469" Content="Add" FontSize="20" Margin="0,10,0,10" Click="addText_Click"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Flyout>
                </Button.Flyout>
```

For example this occupy full screen.I need to control their width , How do I do that?

Comment: You must give your StackPanel a Width and Height.

Comment: afaik this is its default behaviour,, I have wasted a lot of my time to change it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

XAML:

```
<MenuFlyout Placement="Top">
</MenuFlyout>
```

C#:

```
myMenuFlyout.Placement = FlyoutPlacementMode.Top;
```